# I need a hint to fix this issues related to Cython

Tags: python, cython

I have the following files:

`app.py` (there some more complex code)

```
print("Hello, World!")
```

---

`compile.py`

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
ext_modules = [
    Extension("APP",  ["app.py"])
]
setup(
    name = 'AVP',
    cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
    ext_modules = ext_modules
)
```

---

`main.py`

```
from logic import main      # this comes from a compiled binary
main ()
```

---

When I am running this:

`python3 compile.py build_ext --inplace`

I am getting this:

```
(protect) ~/workspace/avp/ (master) $ python3 compile.py build_ext --inplace
running build_ext
skipping 'app.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
building 'APP' extension
clang -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fsanitize=signed-integer-overflow -fsanitize=undefined -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wshadow -fPIC -I/opt/pyenv/versions/3.6.0/include/python3.6m -c app.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/app.o
gcc -pthread -shared -L/opt/pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib -L/opt/pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib -fsanitize=signed-integer-overflow -fsanitize=undefined -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wshadow build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/app.o -o /home/ubuntu/workspace/avp/APP.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-fsanitize=signed-integer-overflow’
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-fsanitize=undefined’
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

To be honest I am not sure what I did wrong because I was following this:

https://medium.com/@xpl/protecting-python-sources-using-cython-dcd940bb188e

It is creating only the `app.c` file and not the `app.so`

Comment: Version of gcc?

Comment: @Alex Please edit your answer and insert that information in it properly formatted.

Comment: Version of clang?

Comment: `(protect) ~/workspace/avp/ (master) $ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.4) 4.8.4
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.`

Comment: `(protect) ~/workspace/avp/ (master) $ clang --version
clang version 3.8.0-2ubuntu3~trusty5 (tags/RELEASE_380/final)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin`

Comment: I just tried this on my machine.


$ clang-3.5  -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fsanitize=signed-integer-overflow -fsanitize=undefined -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wshadow -fPIC -I/opt/pyenv/versions/3.6.0/include/python3.6m -c app.c


And it didnt complain.
Using 
gcc version 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.4) 
and
Ubuntu clang version 3.5.0-4ubuntu2~trusty2 (tags/RELEASE_350/final) (based on LLVM 3.5.0)
Hope this helps.

Comment: I am using Cloud9 it is possible to have any restrictions?

Comment: Well, it doesnt complain about the missing options.
I was getting the same error as you but it went away after I installed clang-3.5.
I didnt have clang installed before, so installing clang must have modified gcc.
Could try uninstalling clang and re-installing it.
It was just to get rid of the missing options error. Am not trying to do what you are doing.

Comment: Thank you very much for your support! I will try now your suggestion!